# OS X: Determine Trash location for a given path

Tags: python, macos, filesystems

Simply moving the file to `~/.Trash/` will not work, as if the file os on an external drive, it will move the file to the main system drive..

Also, there are other conditions, like files on external drives get moved to `/Volumes/.Trash/501/` (or whatever the current user's ID is)

Given a file or folder path, what is the correct way to determine the trash folder? I imagine the language is pretty irrelevant, but I intend to use Python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively, if you're on OS X 10.5, you could use Scripting Bridge to delete files via the Finder.  I've done this in Ruby code [here](http://osx-trash.rubyforge.org/git?p=osx-trash.git;a=blob;f=bin/trash;h=26911131eacafd659b4d760bda1bd4c99dc2f918;hb=HEAD) via RubyCocoa.  The the gist of it is:

```
url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
finder = SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier("com.apple.Finder")
item = finder.items.objectAtLocation(url)
item.delete
```

You could easily do something similar with PyObjC.

Answer (score 6):

Based upon code from http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MoveToTrash I have came up with the following:

```
def get_trash_path(input_file):
    path, file = os.path.split(input_file)
    if path.startswith("/Volumes/"):
        # /Volumes/driveName/.Trashes/<uid>
        s = path.split(os.path.sep)
        # s[2] is drive name ([0] is empty, [1] is Volumes)
        trash_path = os.path.join("/Volumes", s[2], ".Trashes", str(os.getuid()))
        if not os.path.isdir(trash_path):
            raise IOError("Volume appears to be a network drive (%s could not be found)" % (trash_path))
    else:
        trash_path = os.path.join(os.getenv("HOME"), ".Trash")
    return trash_path
```

Fairly basic, and there's a few things that have to be done seperatly, particularly checking if the filename already exist in trash (to avoid overwriting) and the actual moving to trash, but it seems to cover most things (internal, external and network drives)

**Update:** I wanted to trash a file in a Python script, so I re-implemented Dave Dribin's solution in Python:

```
from AppKit import NSURL
from ScriptingBridge import SBApplication

def trashPath(path):
    """Trashes a path using the Finder, via OS X's Scripting Bridge.
    """
    targetfile = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(path)
    finder = SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier_("com.apple.Finder")
    items = finder.items().objectAtLocation_(targetfile)
    items.delete()
```

Usage is simple:

```
trashPath("/tmp/examplefile")
```

Comment: The Python reimplementation didn't work for me, the files were still there after running trashPath on them. The solution proposed by Ashley Clark did work.

Answer (score 3):

A better way is [NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation), which is one of the operations you can use with [-[NSWorkspace performFileOperation:source:destination:files:tag:]](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/performFileOperation:source:destination:files:tag:). The constant's name is another artifact of Cocoa's NeXT heritage; its function is to move the item to the Trash.

Since it's part of Cocoa, it should be available to both Python and Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, without using the scripting bridge, you can do this:

```
from AppKit import NSWorkspace, NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation

source = "path holding files"
files = ["file1", "file2"]

ws = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
ws.performFileOperation_source_destination_files_tag_(NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation, source, "", files, None)
```

Answer (score 2):

The File Manager API has a pair of functions called FSMoveObjectToTrashAsync and FSPathMoveObjectToTrashSync.

Not sure if that is exposed to Python or not.

Answer (score 1):

Another one in ruby:

```
Appscript.app('Finder').items[MacTypes::Alias.path(path)].delete
```

You will need [rb-appscript](http://rubygems.org/gems/rb-appscript) gem, you can read about it [here](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/rb-appscript/index.html)